# Api-platform request issue

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have two entities author and book

```
book     | manytoOne |author
id       |           |id
idAuthor |
```

in the author controller i have an Action function that gets  the author details and all his books (using the forward function to get the books)

```
public function authorDetailsAction($id){

$author= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Author::class)->find($id);

$books= $this->forward('AppBundle:Book:authorBooks',array('id' => $id));

return array('author' => $author, 'books' => $books);

}
```

> but it shows only author informations

or when im rutrning only the books `return $books` i got this error

> The controller must return a response (Array(0 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Book), 1 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Book), 2 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Book)) given). (500 Internal Server Error)

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like you use API Platform, you can achieve what you want without creating a custom controller:

1. Add a filter to the `Author` resource to be able to search an author by name: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization-groups-and-relations#embedding-relations
2. Embed books related to an author directly in the author response: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters#search-filter.

Answer (score 0):

A Symfony controller must always return an instance of the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class. You cannot simply return an arbitrary value, because Symfony wouldn’t know how to render it.

There are two ways to create a `Response` object inside a controller:

First, direct instantiation. For example:

```
$response = new Response("This is my content.", 200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
return $response;
```

Second, if your controller is a child class of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, you can use the `render()` method to access the templating engine:

```
$response = $this->render("foo/bar.html.twig", ["foo" => "bar"]);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
return $response;
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html for more.